# Два массива

Tags: массивы, android

Есть 2 массива:

```
ArrayList<String> One = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Two = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Массивом `One` заполняется `listView` (в Массиве `One` обычный текст).
В массиве `Two` - ссылка на объяснение этого текста т.е. `One` (Пример текста), `Two` (Ссылка на объяснение).
И вот что мне нужно: чтобы при нажатии на `ListView` открывалась ссылка из массива `Two`.

Comment: Все сложно

Comment: Я уже сколько часов голову ломаю =(

Comment: Я же тебе писал, что в массиве надо хранит элемент, а не куски строк....

Comment: Я без понятия как это сделать, покажешь пример буду рад

Comment: Жалуется на add The method add(Element) in the type ArrayList<Element> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
one.add(One.text());

Comment: Кинь свой кусок кода

Comment: У тебя уже массив елементов, с которых ты берешь значение, не надо туда ложить еще текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Element> one = new ArrayList();
for(Element newsheader : newsheaders){ 
    Element One = newsheader.select("a[href]").first(); 
    one.add(One);
}
```

Так вот хранишь элементы, перебераешь и вытягиваешь свои значения

Comment: Elements newsheaders = doc.select("h2.newsheader"); ArrayList<Element> newsOrLink = new ArrayList(); for(Element newsheader : newsheaders){ Element TitleNews = newsheader.select("a[href]").first(); newsOrLink.add(TitleNews); } Как сейчас доставать текст? newsOrLink.text()?

Comment: newsOrLink.get(0).text(); например так с первого элемента.  Ты бы джаву подучил

Comment: Этим и занимаюсь)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на HashMap. В качестве ключа храните обычный текст, в качестве значения - его объяснение. В качестве модели списка берите `.keySet()`.